# Get table header to use pager url drupal 7

Tags: drupal, pagination, themes

I have got a unique issue. In my drupal site, I have got a lot of nodes displayed in a teaser and for each node, I am using a table with a pager.  The problem is, on initial load of the page, the table sort doesn't work.  However, if I use the pager and move to a different page and then back, then the sorting works.

I investigated this issue and found out that on initial load, the url for the header links use the primary link, which is: mysite.com/node?sort=asc&order=Name. After I click on the pager, then the url for the header links, changes to this: mysite.com/mycallbackfunction?_=1348208999187&page=1&nid=13&pager_id=1&sort=desc&order=Name

If you notice, the url obviously are different, which is okay, but the main thing is, the nid is missing in the initial load.  I would like the table headers to use the pager url, or some url that I specify, so the nid would appear in both cases as the function returns nothing if there is no nid.

This is the relevant code in mycallbackfunction which displays the table:

```
  //Attach a theme table 
  $html = theme('table', array(
    'header' => $header,
    'rows' => $rows,
    'attributes' => array(
      "class" => array(
        "my_table_box"
      ),
      "cellspacing" => '0',
      "cellpadding" => '0'
  )));

//Pager theme
  $html .= theme('pager', array(
    'element' => $pager_id,
    'parameters' => array(
      'nid' => $nid,
      'pager_id' => $pager_id),
    'quantity' => ceil($count/5)
  ));
```

Hope someone might have an insight into this weird problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the custom parameter in theme('pager') function.

```
<?php
// e.g.
theme('pager', array('parameters' => array('nid' => $nid))
?>);
```

Let me know if you are looking for something else.

Good Luck!

-Imran